# Multi-platfform process handling

Tags: python, design-patterns

The goal of this code is to handle processes in multiple platforms, Linux initially. Windows later. The high level handler starts and stops a process or a list of processes. The platform specific drivers must conform to the following interface: `open()`, `close()` and `is_open()`. This system is used in test automation.

My objective is creating a reusable, unit-testable and extensible component. It already works and passes a test suite with > 80% coverage.

Please review code and provide feedback.

**typical use case**

```py
        local_directory = dirname(abspath(__file__))
        processes_list = ['./test_process_a.py', './test_process_b.py', './test_process_c.py']
        processes = ProcessHandler(processes_list, local_directory)
        processes.start()
        # The processes do some work
        processes.stop()
```

**process_handler.py**

```py
from process.linux_process_driver import *
from logger.logger_init import *
import argparse

class ProcessHandler:
    """ Class that handles that start and stop of a set of processes. """

    def __init__(self, process_path, cwd, process_driver = LinuxProcessDriver):
        self.__process_path = process_path
        self.__cwd = cwd
        self.__process_driver = process_driver
        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

    def start(self):
        """ Start process(es) """ 

        self.__logger.debug('--> start()')
        process_list = self.set_process_state(True, self.__process_path)
        self.__logger.debug('<-- start()')
        return process_list

    def stop(self):
        """ Stop process(es) in reverse order. """ 

        self.__logger.debug('--> stop()')
        reversed_process_list = list(reversed(self.__process_path))
        process_list = self.set_process_state(False, reversed_process_list)
        self.__logger.debug('<-- stop()')
        return process_list

    def set_process_state(self, state, process_list):
        """ Set process(es) state """ 

        check_open_retries = 3
        self.__logger.debug('--> set_process_state()')
        try:
            for process_path in process_list:
                process = self.__process_driver(process_path, self.__cwd)
                process.close()
                while(process.is_open()): # Sometimes the process is closed and this check is done so fast, that the process still appears open.
                    if(check_open_retries > 0):
                        self.__logger.error('Check open atempts left: ' + str(check_open_retries) + '. Process: ' + process_path + ' could not be closed.')
                        check_open_retries -= 1
                        continue
                    else:
                        raise RuntimeError('Process: ' + process_path + ' could not be closed.')
                if(state == True):
                    process.open()
                    if(not process.is_open()):
                        raise RuntimeError('Process: ' + process_path + ' could not be opened.')
        except Exception as exception:
            self.__logger.error(exception)
            raise
        self.__logger.debug('<-- set_process_state()')
        return process_list
```

**linux_process_driver.py**

```py
import os, signal
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
from logger.logger_init import *

class LinuxProcessDriver:
    local_directory = dirname(abspath(__file__))

    def __init__(self, process_path, cwd = local_directory, os_handler = os):
        self.__logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
        self.__logger.debug('process path input param: ' + process_path)
        last_index = process_path.rindex('/')
        self.__process_name = process_path[last_index + 1:]
        self.__process_path = process_path
        self.__cwd = cwd
        self.__os_handler = os_handler
        self.__logger.debug('process name: ' + self.__process_name)
        self.__logger.debug('process path: ' + self.__process_path)
        self.__logger.debug('process execution directory: ' + self.__cwd)

    def open(self):
        self.__logger.debug('--> open()')
        self.__process = Popen(self.__process_path, cwd = self.__cwd).pid
        self.__logger.info('Opened process ' + self.__process_path + ' at directory ' + self.__cwd)
        self.__logger.debug('<-- open()')

    def close(self):
        self.__logger.debug('--> close()')
        if not self.is_open():
            self.__logger.info('Process ' + self.__process_path + ' was not running.')
            return
        try:
            for pid in reversed(self.__pid_list):
                if(pid != ''):
                    self.__os_handler.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)
                    self.__logger.info('Closed process: ' + self.__process_path + ' with PID ' + pid)
        except Exception as exception:
                self.__logger.error(exception)
                raise
        self.__logger.debug('<-- close()')

    def is_open(self):
        self.__logger.debug('--> is_open()')
        self.__get_pid()
        result = False
        if(len(self.__pid_list) != 0 and self.__pid_list[0].isdigit()):
            result = True
        self.__logger.debug('Process ' + self.__process_path + ' running? ' + str(result))
        self.__logger.debug('<-- is_open()')
        return result

    def __get_pid(self):
        self.__logger.debug('--> __get_pid()')
        linux_cmd_find_pid = 'ps -eo pid,cmd | grep "{0}" | grep -v grep'.format(self.__process_name)
        linux_cmd_find_pid = linux_cmd_find_pid + ' | awk \'{print $1}\''
        process = Popen(linux_cmd_find_pid, shell = True, stdout = PIPE)
        pid, garbage = process.communicate()
        self.__logger.debug('linux output: ' + pid.strip())
        self.__pid_list = pid.splitlines()
        self.__logger.debug('Length of pid list: ' + str(len(self.__pid_list)))
        for pid in self.__pid_list:
            self.__logger.debug('Found process: ' + self.__process_name + ' with PID ' + str(pid))
        self.__logger.debug('<-- __get_pid()')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    """ Script to show usage and test basic functionality. """

    # Create paths
    local_directory = dirname(abspath(__file__))
    logs_directory_relative = "logs"
    logs_directory_absolute = os.path.join(local_directory, logs_directory_relative)
    log_filename = "log_linux_process_driver.py"

    # Create logger
    logger_init(logs_directory_absolute, log_filename)
    logger = logging.getLogger("LOGGER INIT TEST")

    process_path = raw_input('Enter process name: ')
    process = linux_process_driver(process_path)
    process.open()
    if(process.is_open()):
        logger.info('The process was opened.')
    else:
        logger.info('The process could not be opened.')
    process.close()
    if(not process.is_open()):
        logger.info('The process was closed.')
    else:
        logger.info('The process could not be closed.')
```

Comment: Are you trying to recreate something akin to [`psutil`](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: @409_Conflict, I did not know of psutil's existence. psutil looks great and is very much what I intended to do. I will defininetly look into it. On the other hand, I'm new to python and I'm also very interested in having my code reviewed so I can get feedback of how I'm doing. Please review my code and let me know of any feedback you may think. For example, how readable (easy, medium, hard) is my code? Thank you !!

Comment: `if(state == True)` is a rather strange style. I personally don't like it even in languages where parentheses around a condition are mandatory (eg. C, Java, etc.). In those languages I prefer a space between the keyword and left parenthesis: `if (state == True)`. In Pyhon, however, parentheses are not necessary, so it would seem more appropriate to write `if state == True`. Here you can notice that you are comparing a boolean value with `True`, which is superfluous. You can just write `if state`. At this point it's apparent that `state` is not a great name. A better name would be `is_running`.

Comment: Hi @kyrill, thank you for your observation. Very nice refactoring. I come from a C/C++ backgorund. Now, let me ask you if I may, how readable (easy, medium, hard) do you find my code? Thank you!!

Comment: I'd say medium. I like to insert empty lines to separate logically coherent chunks of code. But what I find more problematic is things like `set_process_state` where you perform some operation for a number of elements but break out of the loop as soon as the first error occurs. Maybe it would be better to put the `try` block inside the `for` loop and not the other way around. Another problem here is that if you call `set_process_state` with `state == True`, it will kill the process, which may not be what the user wants or expects. It would be useful to mention this in the docstring.

Comment: Similiar to @kyrill's advice above, you can also change `if(len(self.__pid_list) != 0)` to be simply `if self.__pid_list` since Python will check for nonzero size of array when evaluating an array as a boolean.